# Ruby: Comparing user input with string

Tags: ruby, string, string-comparison

I'm just picking up Ruby. I'm trying to compare two strings in an If statement like so:

```
#get user input
input = gets #type in 'a'

#compare
if input == "a"
    puts "a!"
end
```

This doesn't output anything when i type in 'a'.

I've tried the triple '===', input.eql?, input.equal? - no output

If I use the spaceship, '<=>', it works regardless of input equating to 'a'.

How should I compare strings?

Thank you!

Comment: Ultimately yes, but when I googled specifically "user input matching to string", I didn't see an immediate answer. Perhaps this exchange will serve to help this specific pitfall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably has a new line:

**You can use:** input.chomp.eql? 'a'

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: We got it at the same time! All good, I'll give you the cred. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, use `input = gets.chomp`

`.chomp` will automatically make a new line after `gets` for an example:

```
input = gets #type Ruby 

 if input == "Ruby"   
   puts "I love Ruby!"
 else   
   puts "Invalid input"
 end
```

For this example the output will be `#=> "I love Ruby\n"`

Now if you use `.chomp`:

```
input = gets.chomp #type Ruby

if input == "Ruby"
  puts "I love Ruby!"
else
  puts "Invalid input"
end
```

The output for this will be the same as above without the `\n`

Also in Ruby you can use `if input =~ /a/i` this will make it so that anything that includes `a` will work, in other words you can type a, A and the output will be the same..

Answer (score 1):

gets automatically adds a newline to the input.

we need to switch this to

```
input = gets.chomp
```

which will supply the value without the new line..